# Trying to combines multiple employees' timesheet tables using power query for Power BI report

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am having trouble cleaning the data from timesheet tables from multiple employees.

The timesheets are attendance records and I want to import the data to a single dataset into Power bi for analysis.
The time entries are separated by each employee's Staff ID and dates into a table and there are 78 tables for each employee.

I have tried to use transpose, pivoting the tables, and splitting column 1 with the delimiter of staff ID: but unable to get it to work.

Appreciate the help.

[image: Tables of employee timesheet data Employee clock in-out information for columns and dates for rows.]

Comment: post a usable machine readable data sample of more than one page for more than one employee

Comment: @Talibo, it's not clear what the difficulty without seeing the format of the data ( csv, txt, excel, pdf ). I suggest including screenshots of your source step in PowerQuery and what you want it to look like as well.

Comment: Hi thanks for response, i am not sure how to attach the format of the table from excel here. let me try again.